# Javascript diff between 2 moment objects returns -1

Tags: javascript

So i want to take 2 times on button click, and then upon clicking second one i want to display time passed from first time to second click.
Format should be HH:MM:SS. Now i tried to display it in seconds, hours, days, with and without true, but it always returns -1 or 0.
Other object (vreme2) is just same code as vreme1 but a new object.
Both objects in console log show _isMomentObject: true, so i cant figure it out.

```
    var vreme1;
    var vreme2;
    var pocetno;
    var zavrsno;

    (pocetno = function () {
        document.getElementById("dolazak")
            .value = moment().format('HH:mm:ss');
    })();
    setInterval(pocetno, 1000);

    var dugme1 = document.getElementById('dolazak-btn');
    dugme1.addEventListener('click', function () {
        clearInterval(pocetno);
        var vreme1 = moment();
        dugme1.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

    var pocetnoBtn = document.getElementById('dolazak-btn');

            var rez = vreme2.diff(vreme1, 'seconds', true);
            console.log(rez);
        } else {
            alert('Prvo ste uneli vreme odlaska!');
        }

    });
```

Comment: sounds like `vreme1` is undefined or null.

Comment: Moment
_d: Tue Aug 06 2019 15:50:17 GMT+0200 (Средњеевропско летње време) {}
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", ordinal: ƒ, _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, …}
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
__proto__: Object

and return value -0.001

Comment: where is `vreme2` value set ? I mean you declare the variable but never affect a value

Comment: there are some syntaxerrors in your shown code… if this is your code it cant work, otherwise show us the complete code please.

Comment: To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the function(){} for `dugme1.addEventListener`, you do `var vreme1 = moment();`. That declares a new local variable `vreme1` and sets it, but this local variable is then also **discarded** at the end of the function.

Note that the local variable `vreme1` is not the same as your global variable `vreme1`: they occupy different spots in memory, have a different lifecycle, and have independent values.

If you remove the `var` that is inside the function(){}, then it might work (but I can't verify, because the code that you provided is rather incomplete).